# How to encode bytes in JSON? json.dumps() throwing a TypeError

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to encode a dictionary containing a string of bytes with `json`, and getting a `is not JSON serializable error`:

```py
import base64
import json

data = {}
encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')
data['bytes'] = encoded

print(json.dumps(data))
```

The error I get:

```
TypeError: b'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk\n' is not JSON serializable
```

How can I correctly encode my dictionary containing bytes with JSON?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27837346

Comment: Another option is to use `b'...'.decode('latin1')`, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22621777

Answer (score 110, accepted):

[`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) expects strings in its input. Since [`base64.b64encode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html#base64.b64encode) encodes bytes you need to convert those bytes into a string using the ASCII codec:

```
import base64

encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')  # b'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk' (notice the "b")
data['bytes'] = encoded.decode('ascii')            # 'ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk'
```

Note that to get the original data back you don't need to re-encode it to bytes because `b64decode()` handles ASCII-only strings as well as bytes:

```
decoded = base64.b64decode(data['bytes'])  # b'data to be encoded'
```

Comment: I know this is an old post but you meight want to use `UTF8` instead of `ASCII`

Comment: @JelledeFries: No, because Base64 only ever uses ASCII characters.

Comment: @MartijnPieters technically it's mute point. All ASCII characters are also UTF-8 characters *by design*.  However Jelle de Fries has a point because UTF-8 is so ubiquitous that encoding to anything else ought to be done for good reason.  I see no good reason to chose ASCII over UTF-8.

Comment: @PhilipCouling: except that base64 only ever uses ASCII characters, and if code that is supposed to only produce ASCII codepoints is not in fact doing so, something is broken. I like having such safety valves in place, and being explicit about constraints.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it would just be `encoded.decode()` because `'utf-8'` is the [default argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) to `.decode()`. It would be shorter and also anyone reading the code doesn't need to know about encodings or the difference between ASCII and UTF-8, they just need to know "it's bytes and you need to turn it into a string with `.decode()`". Personally, I wrote software for a couple years before I understood what UTF-8 was. I think it's just unnecessary explicitness, we know it's going to be ASCII, there's no need to error if its not.

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy: yes, ASCII is a subset of UTF8, but just using the default is a shortcut that'll trip you up if the default ever changed or the output of `base64.b64encode()` ever changed to cover more than ASCII (or the function was replaced by accident, etc.). You should **always** be thinking about what codec the bytes are in when decoding, by the way.

Comment: None of those things will ever change and I shouldn't think about that at all, computers should just use one encoding - UTF-8

Comment: @BorisVerkhovskiy: that may well be, but mistakes happen, and Python is highly maleable (you can replace functions dynamically). Better to catch those mistakes as early as possible. Note that I **explicitly talk about this** in my comment from January 2021, too. It's a safety valve, please don't remove safety valves just because it looks shorter.

Answer (score 3):

The other answers have pointed you to a fix for your error. More generally, if your dictionary contains `bytes` objects, you can use a custom encoder class to encode, without having to manually convert each item to base64:

```py
import base64
import json

data = {"bytes": b"some byte string"}

class BytesEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, bytes):
            return base64.b64encode(o).decode("ascii")
        else:
            return super().default(o)

print(json.dumps(data, cls=BytesEncoder))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Martijn mentioned, only strings are json-serializable (using `json`). A bytes object can be converted into a string using a `str()` call by specifying the encoding.

```py
data = {}
encoded = base64.b64encode(b'data to be encoded')
data['bytes'] = str(encoded, encoding='ascii')
#               ^^^          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
json.dumps(data)   # '{"bytes": "ZGF0YSB0byBiZSBlbmNvZGVk"}'
```