# how to encrypt a plain text in pyaes package?

Tags: python-3.x, encryption, cryptography

I tried to encrypt a text in python using `pyaes` package:

```
import os
import pyaes
aes = pyaes.AESModeOfOperationCTR(os.urandom(16))
result = aes.encrypt("test")
```

but I'm getting a error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc8 in position 0: invalid continuation byte

and also I tried `aes.encrypt("test".encode())`

What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I had no issues whatsoever running your code snippet on both Python 3.9 and Python 2.7.18. What is the Python version you are using ?
Could you give a more detailed traceback ?

Comment: hi, my python version is 3.9.2 and this all the traceback `File "C:\Users\DASUSER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\DASUSER1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\wdir\dms_django_react\venv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\utils\encoders.py", line 50, in default
    return obj.decode()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are possibly trying to serialize your result to `json`.

The encryption result is `bytes`, and these bytes could not be directly decoded to a string.

Use **base64** instead, as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40000495/how-to-encode-bytes-in-json-json-dumps-throwing-a-typeerror) question

```py
result = aes.encrypt("test")
to_dump = base64.b64encode(result).decode()

import json
json.dumps(to_dump)  # this would output a b64encoded version of your secret, which could later be decoded and decrypted on the client.
```