# How to send images to PUBSUB google ( Opencv Python )

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

Hello i want to send a `multipart/form-data` form to a pubsub

i have the following data:

```
data = {'uuid' : mId, 'token' : 'd8sd87dvttd', 'objId': str(objData[1].objectID)}
img = cv2.imencode('.jpg', objData[1].getImage())[1].tostring()
post_data = { 'image' : img }
future = self.publisher.publish(
                        self.topic_path, files = json.dumps(post_data).encode('utf-8'), data=json.dumps(data).encode('utf-8'), type="data1"
                    )
```

this code returns the following error:

```
TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable
```

any one can help me ? i cant find any example of how to send images to pubsub google.

Answer (score 1):

PubSub messages do not have any concept of images, they just contain data that must be a binary string (Python type `bytes`). Your form data thus needs to be encoded as a binary string before it can be published as a PubSub message.

The error you are seeing does not happen in the `publish()` method, but instead when the code tries to serialize one of the arguments to JSON, example:

```py
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps({'foo': b'bar'})  # <-- bar is a BYTE string
...
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Check the contents of `data` and `post_data` for any binary strings, with `img` being the main suspect. You will need to convert it to text data first using an encoding such as [Base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) so that `json.dumps()` will know how to serialize it:

```py
import base64
post_data = {'image': base64.b64encode(img).decode()}

# Alternative conversion to text, but can be less space-efficient due to
# how non-ASCII characters are serialized in JSON - \uxxxx escapes:
post_data = {'image': img.decode('latin1')}
```

(also see the [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837346/how-to-include-pictures-bytes-to-a-json-with-python-encoding-issue) for more details)

Of course, subscribers will have to do just the opposite conversions to get back the binary image data from the received messages.